# XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP shows KDE even though I'm running gnome (in some apps)

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, environment-variables

I've installed kubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. At some point I've decided to try gnome and installed `ubuntu-desktop`. I've stick with that and removed most kde/plasma packages few weeks back. I've even successful upgraded to 18.10 and in general have no major issues.

However, I've noticed some weirdness that I'm not sure how to fix or debug further.

When I try to inspect `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` from gnome-terminal I get this:

```
$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP 
ubuntu:GNOME
```

However, when I do the same from a terminal within emacs, I get:

```
$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP 
KDE
```

This is really annoying, as some app rely on it. E.g. the default behavior in emacs is to use `xdg-open` to open urls. But with `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` set to `KDE`, `xdg-open` delegates to `kde-open5` which doesn't exist and fails.

How can I debug it further? I wonder where this is being set up to KDE. Any hints greatly appreciated.

[image: XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague put me on the right track, and then [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44012/2228) filled in the blanks.

I'm using spacemacs and it "caches" your environment the first time you start it in `~/.spacemacs.env`.

Removing the file:

```
$ rm ~/.spacemacs.env
```

and then asking spacemacs to recreate it with:

```
[M-x] spacemacs/force-init-spacemacs-env
```

resolved the issue.

[Further reading](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/616ca1443d3be97779a5188bdd999a7d6ea87d93/core/core-env.el#L32)